# Fix Memory allocation error in MLCP Import

Tags: marklogic, mlcp

We are trying to IMPORT huge data set using MLCP but we are getting **SVC-MEMALLOC: Memory allocation error: VirtualAlloc 268435456** and IMPORT failed.

Since we are invoking MLCP from java api, we can not go with setting **JVM_OPTS** in the command line also we can not set `-thread_count 1 -transaction_size 1 -batch_size 1`.

We need a solution to pass **JVM_OPTS** through MLCP java API.

Please help us to fix this issue.

Comment: Is there any reason that you can't set your VM env variable like `set JAVA_OPTS="-Xmx4g" ?  If you use Gradle, then you have more control over JVM memory from both build and task/command line perspective...